# jCarousel jQuery ajax loading 1000 records

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm using jCarousel to present a vertical scolling list of +-1000 names. I am using ajax to load the data 100 records at a time then when all the data has loaded I just let the jCarousel loop in the DOM. I have the ajax and loop all working but would like to make the code work no matter how large the total record count becomes.

1) I'd like to eliminate the 1201 fixed number and use a variable. 2) I currently loop on every record I see (carousel.first) to see if it matches my reload position(s) (albeit the loop is ony 12x it still seems a little "loopy")

Any suggestions on improving this?

```
        function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)   {
        //if (carousel.has(carousel.first, carousel.last)) {                                                
        //return;           
        //}             
        var getCount = 100;     // Number of records to grab at a time
        var maxCount = 1201;    // total possible number of records
        var visible = 9;        // the number of records you can see in the window so this creates a pre-load by this number of records         
        for (var i = 1;  i < maxCount; i+=getCount ) { 
            if (carousel.first === 1 || carousel.first === (i-visible)){                
                var getFrom = i;                    
                var getTo = getFrom+(getCount-1);
                //alert('TOP Record ='+carousel.first+'\n Now GET '+getFrom+'-'+getTo);                 
                jQuery.get('#ajaxscript#', {
                        first: getFrom,
                        last: getTo
                    },
                    function(xml) {
                        mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, getFrom, getTo, xml);
                    },
                'xml'
                );                  
            break;
            }
        }
    };
```